# ASP PAGES ON IIS 5.1 and COM DLL

Tags: iis, com, asp-classic

I have ASP Pages hosted on IIS 5.1 that uses the COM DLL (VB).
I am browsing the ASP page and it is giving me an Server.CreateObject error.

I registered and Unregsitered my COM components. I registered it again.

I am trying to figure out how IIS does the mapping for the COM DLL and
the reason for the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you gave us the exact error message that you are receiving. In the meantime check [this out](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175804).